# Creating a Label via a method in a class

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

I am slowly developing a custom button (while learning how to implement classes etc).

I have a ViewController, which imports a SuperButton.h (UIControl) and then creates an instance of the SuperButton. (This works, as proved by a NSLog.)

**But I cannot get the method in SuperButton to display a Label.
I think this might have something to with the '.center' value or the 'addSubview' command?**

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Here is my SuperButton.m code:

```
#import "SuperButton.h"

@implementation SuperButton
@synthesize firstTitle;
@synthesize myLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
- (void) shoutName{
    NSLog(@"My name is %@", firstTitle);

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 50.0f);
    self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
    self.myLabel.text = @"Come on, don't be shy.";
    self.myLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.myLabel.center = self.center;
    [self addSubview:self.myLabel];
}
```

Here is the code in my ViewController:

```
- (void) makeButton{
    SuperButton *button1 = [[SuperButton alloc] init];
    button1.firstTitle = @"Mr. Ploppy";
    [button1 shoutName];
}
```

(EDIT:) Just in case, here's the SuperButton.h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SuperButton : UIControl

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *myLabel;

- (void) shoutName;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer elsewhere.
I needed to addSubview the 'button'. My working code now looks like this:

```
- (void) makeButton{
    SuperButton *button1 = [[SuperButton alloc] init];
    button1.firstTitle = @"Mr. Ploppy";
    [button1 shoutName];
    [self.view addSubview:button1.myLabel];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:button1.myLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your button not with `initWithFrame:` method, but with simple `init`. This makes the button of `CGRectZero` size. Change this line:

```
SuperButton *button1 = [[SuperButton alloc] init];
```

to this:

```
SuperButton *button1 = [[SuperButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 50.0f)];
```

or add a call to `setFrame:` after initializing your button.

Comment: Thanks for that, tried it, but the Labels are still not showing up. Anything else I could try?

Comment: Yes, try removing the line with `self.myLabel.center = self.center`